# Make an image appear on top of div

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to make an image appear outside of the parent div so it looks like the image is sitting on the div without increasing the height of the parent div. However, no matter what i've tried the image just gets cut off by the parent div and doesn't show everything.

I have a js fiddle setup to hopefully explain what I'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/h7esvfsr/

```
#navWrap{
    float: right; 
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    height: 50px;
}
#navLogo{
    float: left;
}
#navLogo img{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Snippet below:

```css
.gridContainer {
  width: 89.0217%;
  max-width: 1232px;
  padding-left: 0.4891%;
  padding-right: 0.4891%;
  margin: auto;
}
#navWrap {
  float: right;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 50px;
}
#navLogo {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
#navLogo img {
  width: 200px;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  /* half of the width  */
  margin-top: -50px;
  /* half of the height */
  ;
}
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.topnav li {
  float: left
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #269C1E;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div id="nav-anchor"></div>
  <nav class="gridContainer clearfix" id="nav">
    <div id="navWrap">
      <div id="navLogo">
        <img src="http://graphxnation.com/gxn_logo_large.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll most likely have to put `position: absolute; z-index: 2;` on your `#navLogo img`. You can play around with the positioning using `left: 0px` *or* `right: 0px;` (changing 0px to the necessary value, of course). Also, a note: Make sure you're using `float` properly. Your page has multiple elements with 0px height, which is generally a good indicator that your floats are not properly cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *position* the image *absolutely*:

1. Add `width: 200px` - the same the image to the `navLogo`
2. Add `position: absolute` to `navLogo img` (you can adjust position now using `left` and `top`)
3. Clear the `float`s using `overflow: hidden` to `navLogo`, `navWrap` and `gridContainer` and remove that from `menu`
4. Add `position: relative` to `menu`

See demo below - added a `section` to simulate scroll on content below the header nav:

```css
.gridContainer {
  width: 89.0217%;
  max-width: 1232px;
  padding-left: 0.4891%;
  padding-right: 0.4891%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navWrap {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}
#navLogo {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navLogo img {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  /* half of the width  */
  margin-top: -50px;
  /* half of the height */
  ;
}
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: relative;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.topnav li {
  float: left
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #269C1E;
}
/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
section {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div id="nav-anchor"></div>
  <nav class="gridContainer clearfix" id="nav">
    <div id="navWrap">
      <div id="navLogo">
        <img src="http://graphxnation.com/gxn_logo_large.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<section></section>
```

Comment: @ZeddAlmighty let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

Comment: Your code works on the jsfiddle and would work for what im doing but when i implemented into my existing project it gave me weird results. I have jquery for data-stellar-background-ratio effect and also have the jquery plugin to sticky the navigation menu after it scrolls up. So it put the image on the top of the page and when i scroll up it gave me the same "cutt off" problem i was having before. Hope i explained that right.

Comment: you have to give `position: relative` to an outer wrapper too... but now you have another problem that the image goes behind... to solve this maybe you have to change your markup too...

Comment: @ZeddAlmighty never mind - see the updated answer and let me know your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: @ZeddAlmighty great :) Thanks!